# Saving matrix in Rdata and updating Rdata file

Tags: r, rdata

I have a matrix:

```
mat<-matrix(data=1:30,ncol=10,nrow=3)
```

I would like to save this to Rdata:

```
save(mat, file="m.Rdata")
```

Then load it back:

```
m<-load("m.Rdata")
```

Then look at its contents:

```
m
[1] "mat"
```

All it displays is the name of the matrix saved but the values are lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Also

Once I have saved the matrix I would like to create a new matrix:

```
mat2<-matrix(data=30:59,ncol=10,nrow=3)
```

I would then like to save this mat2 into the same Rdata file, what is the right procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `load("m.Rdata")`

And try `ls()`. You should see your matrix name.

Consider reading on basics of R - [The Workspace](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/workspace.html)

Comment: excellent thanks! Because I have another very similar question please see my edit.

Comment: Use `save.image()` instead of `save()`. `save.image()` will save all your objects(mat,mat2,etc.) to `.Rdata` at current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
write.table(mat, file="m.Rdata")
m<-read.table("m.Rdata")
```

Comment: Hi @Magdalena, the OP is actually asking about saving the objects. It's a bit specific to R. https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/rdata-files.html.

Comment: @StupidWolf you have right, I didn't notice the second question, because I was looking for recipe to save and load only one object ;) and when I dig deeper  I see that load("m.Rdata") works, but I cannot try to assign result to  any vairable